# Where to download revoked certificates from?

Tags: tls, public-key-infrastructure, x.509

I don't want the certificate revocation lists. I want actual full on revoked certificates for test purposes.

For example, [Flame used a signed rogue cert](http://www.techdirt.com/articles/20120604/04301819188/flame-malware-signed-rogue-microsoft-cert-once-again-highlights-problems-with-relying-certs.shtml) and in [2001 someone posed as Microsoft and got rogue certs for them from Verisign](http://news.cnet.com/2100-1001-254586.html).  I think it'd be interesting to have both of these certs.

Like one thing I'm curious about: was the `CRLDistribituionPoint` extension present in them? I'm curious about other things too but if someone has them that'd be great. Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to test?  You can probably set up your own CA and test the scenarios yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use a [MD5 rogue certificate](http://www.win.tue.nl/hashclash/rogue-ca/) (directly to [the demo page](https://i.broke.the.internet.and.all.i.got.was.this.t-shirt.phreedom.org/)). Also see [the research paper](http://www.phreedom.org/research/rogue-ca/).

I also found [a research on the rogue certificates from March 2011](http://www.unrest.ca/comodogate-part-2).

Maybe searching the Internet for those black-listed rogue certificates' serial number will help:

```
00:b0:b7:13:3e:d0:96:f9:b5:6f:ae:91:c8:74:bd:3a:c0 login.live.com
00:e9:02:8b:95:78:e4:15:dc:1a:71:0a:2b:88:15:44:47 login.skype.com
00:39:2a:43:4f:0e:07:df:1f:8a:a3:05:de:34:e0:c2:29 login.yahoo.com
00:3e:75:ce:d4:6b:69:30:21:21:88:30:ae:86:a8:2a:71 login.yahoo.com
00:d7:55:8f:da:f5:f1:10:5b:b2:13:28:2b:70:77:29:a3 login.yahoo.com
00:04:7e:cb:e9:fc:a5:5f:7b:d0:9e:ae:36:e1:0c:ae:1e mail.google.com
00:f5:c8:6a:f3:61:62:f1:3a:64:f5:4f:6d:c9:58:7c:06 www.google.com
00:92:39:d5:34:8f:40:d1:69:5a:74:54:70:e1:f2:3f:43 addons.mozilla.org
```

These serial numbers are from the Microsoft certificate store after applying the relevant updates.

I did some searching, but all i found was the link [4](http://www.unrest.ca/comodogate-part-2) I already mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to obtain revoked certificates for testing by opening the `Certificates` Snapin in Microsoft Management Console and looking in the `Untrusted Certificates` store. There you will see a large number of revoked certificates. Right click and export to get them into a file.